# How to override SAPUI5's Hook Methods

Tags: user-interface, sapui5

I want to call the hook methods **onBeforeRendering** and **onAfterRendering** externally. My requirement is, when my 3/4 ajax calls complete that time I am rendering UI parts after that I need to call those two methods.

Comment: I think your architecture is wrong if you depend on AJAX calls completion for calling the `onBeforeRendering` / `onAfterRendering` event hooks (because that's what they are, event hooks, not methods). I would suggest using the AJAX calls promiss `done()` and/or `fail()` to do extra rendering needed

Comment: @Qualiture- Thanks. my requirement is there is one screen, I load data using ajax call( It must be synchronous ) then Depends on data I need to render  screen layout. I must have use promise objects. In success of ajax I need to build screen. I am registering events in **onAfterRendering**. So After rendering screen I need to call the onAfterRendering .

Comment: Why not register your events in the AJAX call's `done()` (or `always()`) promises, and render the extra screen elements there? And why must your AJAX calls be synchronous? The side-efect of this is your screen stays blank, leaving your user waiting for the screen to be loaded instead of at least rendering something in advance, and render the extra screen elements after a successful ajax call?

Comment: 1) Need to call 3/4 Ajax calls. It takes lot of time for each ajax, So Need to call synchronous. 2) We are creating controls in some other files. 3) each control has specific id, So we need to register event in onAfterRendering

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

As said, I think your architecture is wrong. I would have build it something like this:

```js
var self = this;

$.ajax(firstURL, {
    method: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
}).fail(function(response) {
    // handle error
}).done(function(data) {
    // do something with the returned data from first call
    $.ajax(secondURL, {
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
    }).fail(function(response) {
        // handle error
    }).done(function(data) {
        // do something with the returned data from second call
        $.ajax(thirdURL, {
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
        }).fail(function(response) {
            // handle error
        }).done(function(data) {
            // build extra UI elements, for example:
            var someContainer = self.getView().byId("myContainer"); // ui element where you add more controls
            someContainer.addContent(new com.initrode.MyCustomControl({ 
                value : data.someProperty, 
                change : self.doSomething
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

As you see:

- No calls to `onBeforeRendering/AfterRendering`
- AJAX calls are nested, yet asynchronous (the Promises solves the "synchronous" issue here)
- Set your custom control event handlers (in this case, `change`) inline, so no extra event registration needed
- There is no need to set any control's ID (except for the layout element where you need to add the extra controls needed after your ajax calls have all successfully finished)

Answer (score 0):

As @Qualiture said in the comment, you cannot call those methods as they are hooks, being called by the framework before and after the rendering of a control.

You can however "ask" for a rerendering of the control, which in turn will call both hooks, by calling `oControl.rerender()` or `oControl.invalidate()`

Answer (score 0):

**I dont know if you can do it for your scenario**, but in a similar situation I was able to toggle on the fly rendering (as soon as all the ajax calls needed for a control are completed, the control is rendered) by leveraging model binding in the application.

i.e if a control requires some 'data' object to be loaded, bind the control to a model '/data' that will be updated by your ajax call and manage your control visible attribute with something like {= ${/data}||false }

Actually this is somehow relying on the framework to call the renderer function of the control when it detects a change in the model.